# pip install ... Failed with error code 1

Tags: software-installation, python, virtualenvwrapper

I'm trying to configure my new system with Ubuntu 13.10 but pip won't let me install anything. No matter what package I try to install I always get the error:

```
...failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_mensen/...
```

followed by a directory for whatever package I was trying to install.

I am trying to install *virtualenvwrapper*, amongst some other tools.

I have setup tools, and all the necessary python-dev tools.

I wonder if the problem has anything to do with virtualenv since *zsh* always gives me the error

```
zsh virtualenvwrapper plugin: Cannot find virtualenvwrapper.sh. Please install with `pip install virtualenvwrapper`.
```

And when I run `virtualenv` in the terminal

I get...

```
The program 'virtualenv' is currently not installed.
```

but `sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv` gives me

```
python-virtualenv is already the newest version.
```

These might be separate issues as I've been trying to configure multiple things at once...

Answer (score 1):

first of all never use apt-get to install virtualenv. Hell I want to say never use sudo to install virtualenv but I don't want to make your life more complicated right know.

Did you include virtualenvwrapper in your `.zshrc`, I've got a billion question, better to remove everything, [here's how to install it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324558/whats-the-proper-way-to-install-pip-virtualenv-and-distribute-for-python) if you want to take a look

```
curl -O http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
sudo python ez_setup.py
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install virtualenv
sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Maybe not the best method but it will always work.

Back to my question: Did you include `virtualenvwrapper` in your `.zshrc` I put my money on: No.

so create a virtualenv folder like so for example `mkdir /.virtualenvs` and then open `~/.zshrc` in your favorite editor and include

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

and lastly do

`source .zshrc` and `source $HOME/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`